# Use the parameters from URL on the page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I have to use parameter from url on the page.

For example, URL is smth like: `url.com/index.html?username`. 
I need to take this "username" show it on the page, and use it several times to get the right link.

```
<img src='http://url.com/project/{{---username here---}}/{{id}}.png' alt='' />
```

I've tried to do it with `$location.search`. But it doesn't work. It shows "cannot read property search of undefined" :((
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how should I do it in the right way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: which routing you are using `ngRoute` or `ui-router`?

Comment: I think you should assing the value to $scope variable and then use + to concatnate it.
like:
in controller 
$scope.id = "A1B2C3";
and in the viwe
<img src='http://url.com/project/'+{{id}}+'.png' alt='' />

Comment: Do you inject `$location` service in your controller? From the error it's obvious that `$location` is not defined.

Comment: @AvneshShakya ngRoute

Comment: @MRB now I have the error like this one:  $location is not defined :(

Comment: You need to inject in your controller.

Comment: It might be helpful to post your controller.

Comment: Also, if you're doing this several times throughout your app w/ the same username, it would be easiest to put this in a service.

Comment: @Daryushka Posting code can help you and others to find out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[**$location.search()**][1]` to get the `params` as an object. Try after enabling the HTML5mode. 
In your app config, enable `HTML5Mode` like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

and then ,

```
var params = $location.search();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need an parameter from URL use it like this

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
searchObject['foo'] //  => 'bar'
searchObject.foo  //  => 'bar'
```